# Java change Label image

Tags: java, javafx

I have two different StackPanes with HBoxes I want to change the image of a label in the second StackPane with a Label(MouseListener) in the first StackPane I think the problem is that the Label doesn't gets repainted or reloaded

First StackPane:

```
 Label label= new Label("",new ImageView(ClearSpace));

    label.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, (MouseEvent event) -> {
        HotBar hb = new HotBar();

        if(hb.getX1() == 0){
            hb.setImageX1(5);
       }
        event.consume();
    });
```

Second StackPane(HotBar):

```
public Label x1;
Image image= new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/images/Test.png"));

...

Label x1 = new Label("",new ImageView(image));

...

public void setImage(int i){
if(i == 5){
x1.setGraphic(new ImageView(image2));
}
}
```

I think these are the importantst parts of hte code

setImage() is definetly working if you use it below `Label x1 = ...` it works

Comment: This is not clear. What is a `HotBar`, what is `setImageX1`. What is `i`? Are you sure it is 5. Can you format your code?

Comment: @matt I put the complete code on GitHub

Comment: https://github.com/MaxiMittel/HelpStackOverflow

Comment: One thing I've noticed is that you're declaring x1 twice. It's declared as public Label x1; at the top and then Label x1 = new Label("", new ImageView(image)); later in the code. So, you've got two differently scoped x1 variables in there. I suspect the second should not have the word Label prefixed there, if you wish to instantiate the more global Label. And if that second x1 is not being added to your UI, then there will be zero discernible effect for an image change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `EventHandler` you create a new instance of `HotBar` on which you do changes, but this instance is not linked to the scene.

Instead you should pass the instance of `HotBar` into the other class and use that in your event handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
package helloworld;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * Created by matt on 3/22/16.
 */
public class SwapLabel  extends Application {
    int i = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Pane root = new Pane();
        Image img1 = new Image("http://www.logotemplater.com/freelogostemplates/voope-free-logo-template.png", true);
        Image img2 = new Image("http://www.logotemplater.com/freelogostemplates/zoozz-vector-logo-template-sample.png", true);

        Label l = new Label("", new ImageView(img1));
        l.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, e->{
            i = (i+1)%2;
            if(i==0){
                l.setGraphic(new ImageView(img1));
            }else{
                l.setGraphic(new ImageView(img2));
            }
        });
        root.getChildren().add(l);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 200, 200));
        primaryStage.show();


    }
}
```

This appears to be what you are trying to do, but this works. So most likely something else is happening.

Comment: Yeah but the label I want to change is in an other class but @hotzst had the solution but thanks for your efforts